# change the ndb.StringProperty()

Tags: python, html, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Python. I am writing an online application form, which users can enter their name, phone, email and select a class. The question is that once user enter the data of name, phone , email, it will present the result on the next page, and systematically at the main page. However, when users select the class option from the HTML select option, the result cannot be presented at the next page and the main page. How can I adjust the ndb.StringProperty() to get the value from the select option?

```
class Contact(ndb.Model):
name = ndb.StringProperty()
phone = ndb.StringProperty()
email = ndb.StringProperty()
classselect = ndb.StringProperty()
date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

@classmethod
def query_contact(cls, ancestor_key):
    return cls.query(ancestor=ancestor_key).order(-cls.date)
`class MainHandler(Handler):
def get(self):

    email = "abc@def.com"

    ancestor_key = ndb.Key("Email", email or "*nocell*")
    contacts = Contact.query_contact(ancestor_key).fetch(20)

    self.render('mainPage.html', contacts = contacts)

    class Newcontact(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
    email = "abc@def.com"
    new_name = self.request.get('name')
    new_phone = self.request.get('phone')
    new_email = self.request.get('email')
    new_classselect = self.request.get('classselect')
    newcontactitem = Contact(parent=ndb.Key("Email", email or "*nocell*"), 
    name = new_name, phone = new_phone, email = new_email,classselect = 
    new_classselect)
    newcontactitem.put()

    self.response.out.write('<html><body>New Contact has been added<pre>')
    self.response.out.write('<P>'+cgi.escape("Name: " + new_name))
    self.response.out.write('<P>'+cgi.escape("Phone: " + new_phone))
    self.response.out.write('<P>'+cgi.escape("Email: " + new_email))
    self.response.out.write('<P>'+cgi.escape("classselect:+"new_classselect))
    self.response.out.write('<P><input type ="button" onclick="location.href 
    = document.referrer" value="回到上一頁"></input>')
    self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')

   app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   ('/', MainHandler),
   ('/insertcontact', Newcontact),], debug=True)`
```

HTML select option, these are typed in the template:

```
<body>  
    <form  action="/insertcontact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>Name:</div>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{name}}">
        <div>Phone number:</div> 
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="{{phone}}">
        <div>Email address:</div> 
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{email}}">

        <div>classselect:</div>
        <select name="YourClass"value="">
        <option value="A">CLASS A</option>
        <option value="B">CLASS B</option>
        <option value="C">CLASS C</option>
        </select>
        <div>gender:</div>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">female

        <div>
        <input type="submit" name="newcontact">
    </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    {% for contact in contacts %}
    <div>
        <div>{{contact.name}} - {{contact.phone}} - {{contact.email}- 
   {{contact.classselect}}</div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </body> 
   </html>
```

Results:
[image: the page after user entered application info]

Answer (score 0):

I think in your HTML body

```
<select name="YourClass" value="">
```

should be

```
<select name="classselect" value="">
```